# Syntax Error trying to open URL in XML Format

Tags: python, url, urllib3

Python3
The URLs I'm trying to open:
https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid=3534&usesystem=30000142
The typeID is variable.

I've tried many different ways of opening this and have reached the furthest I can get. Here's the code:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
import urllib3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xmltodict
loc = "C:\\Users\\nhoff\\AutomatedTrader\\Data.xls"
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
typeID = sheet.col_values(0)
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
score = 1
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
for i in typeID[1:]:
    url = "https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat?typeid=" + str(i) + "&usesystem=30000142"
    try:
        resp = http.request("GET", url)
        print(resp.data.decode('utf-8'))
    except urllib3.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
        print(error)
```

The url reads as a b-string so I have the decode. When it runs, it doesn't run the exception. It appears to actually open. But when I run that print, I get this:

```
"strconv.ParseUint: parsing \"18.0\": invalid syntax"
"strconv.ParseUint: parsing \"19.0\": invalid syntax"
"strconv.ParseUint: parsing \"20.0\": invalid syntax"
"strconv.ParseUint: parsing \"21.0\": invalid syntax"
```

I don't know what that invalid syntax is. The data is XML. Any ideas?

Comment: what does the response resp look like?

Comment: I assume that's the `print(resp.data.decode('utf-8'))`. What do you get if you put a `print(resp)` just before that?

Comment: @randomer64 If I print resp without the data, i get this: <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x000002C6E7EE29C8>
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x000002C6E7EEB788>
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x000002C6E8AF3888>
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x000002C6E7EEB448>
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x000002C6E7EE2788>

Comment: consider looking at module `requests` - you can then `resp=requests.get(url, data=data)` where `data={"typeid":3534, "usesystem":30000142}`